# How to Merge Two Dataframes Without Losing Any Rows

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames:

```
df1 =

Id ColA ColB ColC
1  aa   bb   cc
3  11   ww   55
5  11   bb   cc


df2 =

Id ColD ColE ColF
1  ff   ee   rr
2  ww   rr   55
3  hh   11   22
4  11   11   cc
5  cc   bb   aa
```

I need to merge these two data frames to get the following result:

```
result =

Id ColA ColB ColC  ColD  ColE  ColF
1  aa   bb   cc    ff    ee    rr
2  NaN  NaN  NaN   ww    rr    55
3  11   ww   55    hh    11    22
4  NaN  NaN  NaN   11    11    cc
5  11   bb   cc    cc    bb    aa
```

I do the merging this way:

```
import pandas as pd

result = pd.merge(df1,df2,on='Id')
```

However my result looks as follows instead of the expected above-shown result:

```
result = 
Id ColA ColB ColC  ColD  ColE  ColF
1  aa   bb   cc    ff    ee    rr
3  11   ww   55    hh    11    22
5  11   bb   cc    cc    bb    aa
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation of `merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), you need to specify the `'how'` parameter as `outer` (the default is `inner`, which is consistent with what you're getting):

> **outer**: use union of keys from both frames (SQL: full outer join)
>
> **inner**: use intersection of keys from both frames (SQL: inner join)

Comment: Something to note is that whilst the default for merge() is "inner", the default for join() is left. So if you are working with index joins be mindful.